# Neo4j import data with queries

Tags: import, neo4j

I searched in this forum and googled but I can't find a solution for my special problem. I have to create a new graph database (neo4j, cypher) and I have to create many data. Something like:

```
CREATE (:Mitglied { userID:1, vorname:"Jennifer", nachname:"Koch", geburtstag:"1977-12-11" }),
(:Mitglied { userID:2, vorname:"Lina", nachname:"Hansen", geburtstag:"1984-04-08" }), 
(:Mitglied { userID:3, vorname:"Paul", nachname:"Brandt", geburtstag:"1956-08-13" }), 
(:Mitglied { userID:4, vorname:"Sophie", nachname:"Peters", geburtstag:"1972-12-24" }), 
(:Mitglied { userID:5, vorname:"Manuel", nachname:"Graf", geburtstag:"1996-02-06" }),
...
```

So I tried to execute the shell batch (Neo4jShell.bat) with C#, copy & paste with some data into webadmin. Without success :( My code (start a new process and used inputstream for inserting every line) stopped after short time, nothing happened (either with the data nor with the program). Webadmin needs loooooong time for only 500 Creates. I have 2,100,000 Creates...

So can anybody of you guys help me and say what I can do? I haven't got any idea at the moment :(
It is for study, so importing relational database is not a solution - the data must be created with queries.. But because of the mass of data it should happend automatically ;)

Thank you very much!

Comment: def. use parameters and in the shell use a file `neo4j-shell -file import.cql` and put `begin .... commit` statements around blocks of 20-40k create statements

Comment: Also see: http://neo4j.org/develop/import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in your comment you're using `C#`, but are you versed in Java? If so, you can use the [***batch inserter***](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M04/batchinsert.html), which is meant for this type of large, one time ingestion.

If not, is using a [***List of Maps***](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-create.html#create-create-multiple-nodes-from-map) any faster?

Comment: I agree with Nicolas on the batch-importer. But I also wrote a bunch of additional tools for importing data, you can put your raw data in csv and then import via parametrized cypher.
https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies! Is there any chance to execute cypher commands with the batch inserter? For example searching for people with the name xyz? Otherwise I have to change some algorithm ;)

Comment: My instinct is to say no, as the Batch Inserter make several changes to the graph Database object you manipulate that cypher may not like.

Comment: Thank you very much! I currently program my java program for the batch inserter and it seems that it works :) But currently I see no chance to execute cypher commands, "only" data itself. But thats okay, it works and that make me happy ;) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem that I found was manually executing queries in C#. I had a database of university students.
Here's my code:

```
StringBuilder query_text = new StringBuilder();
query_text.Append("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \"file:C:/.../students.csv\" AS csvLine ");
query_text.Append("MERGE(faculty: Faculty { name: csvLine.faculty}) ");
query_text.Append("MERGE(university: University { name: csvLine.university }) ");
query_text.Append("CREATE(student: Student { studentid: csvLine.student_id, name: csvLine.name, surname: csvLine.surname, address: csvLine.address, faculty: csvLine.faculty, university: csvLine.university}) ");
query_text.Append("CREATE(student) -[:STUDIES]->(faculty) ");
query_text.Append("CREATE(faculty) -[:OF]->(university)");
CypherQuery query = new CypherQuery(query_text.ToString(), new Dictionary<string, object>(), CypherResultMode.Set);
try {
    ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<Studentas>(query);
}
catch(Exception e){ }
```